# How can i create a Dynamic Multi-Select List in hippo cms?

Tags: hippocms

I am trying to create a Dynamic Multi-Select List. I tried to add a DynamicDropdown and added Multiple in  Fields properties but throws an error:

An error has occurred, sorry for that.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException:
>   org.onehippo.forge.selection.frontend.plugin.DynamicDropdownPlugin
>   does not support fields that are multiple: please use
>   org.onehippo.forge.selection.frontend.plugin.DynamicMultiSelectPlugin
>   for that. Field name is *. Failed to instantiate plugin class
>   'org.onehippo.forge.selection.frontend.plugin.DynamicDropdownPlugin'
>   for wicket id
>   'home.cluster.cms-static.plugin.servicesLoader.cluster.cms-services.plugin.defaultEditorFactory.cluster.cms-editor0.plugin.editorPlugin.cluster.*default*.plugin.preview.cluster.*default*.plugin.dynamicdropdown-preview.cluster..plugin.home.cluster.cms-static.plugin.servicesLoader.cluster.cms-services.plugin.defaultEditorFactory.cluster.cms-editor0.plugin.editorPlugin.cluster.*default*.plugin.preview.cluster.*default*.plugin.dynamicdropdown.cluster.*default*.service.wicket.id'
>   in plugin
>   'home.cluster.cms-static.plugin.servicesLoader.cluster.cms-services.plugin.defaultEditorFactory.cluster.cms-editor0.plugin.editorPlugin.cluster.*default*.plugin.preview.cluster.*default*.plugin.dynamicdropdown-preview.cluster..plugin.home.cluster.cms-static.plugin.servicesLoader.cluster.cms-services.plugin.defaultEditorFactory.cluster.cms-editor0.plugin.editorPlugin.cluster.*default*.plugin.preview.cluster.*default*.plugin.dynamicdropdown.cluster.*default*.plugin.root'
>   (JcrPluginConfig:/hippo:namespaces/system/DynamicDropdown/editor:templates/*default*/root)

Comment: Provide more info, specific details, code if necessary if you want help from someone.

Answer (score 1):

Indeed the DynamicDropdownPlugin is not meant for multi-selects, you should use the DynamicMultiSelectPlugin. Easiest to install using Essentials set=up tool, see 'Add a Selection Field to a Document Type
Using the Setup Application' at https://documentation.bloomreach.com/library/concepts/plugins/selections/configuration.html

HTH
Jeroen